# Help identifying a weird arrow found in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I was clearing out a Dwarven ruin in Skyrim (Mzinchaleft), and when looking around, I found an arrow (like literally from a bow and arrow kind of thing) just lying on the ground. The arrow is super short, less than half the length of a regular arrow, and it has a flaming, red and orange glowing tip, like it's heated. I can move it around, but I'm not able to pick it up or activate it in any way. I feel really dumb for asking this, as it's probably something obvious that I missed, but I'm just not sure.

Comment: An image of the arrow would probably be helpful

Answer (score 6):

That sounds like the [Dwarven Sphere Centurion Arrow](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dwarven_Sphere_Centurion_Arrow#Dwarven_Sphere_Centurion_Arrow):

[image: Dwarven Sphere Centurion Arrow]

[Dwarven spheres](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dwarven_Sphere) fire them, but the player can't pick them up.

(I placed a pile of the arrows on the ground using the console for that screenshot.)

Comment: I feel like I've seen a much shorter version of that arrow, that's just an arrowhead with hardly any stem. It might be added by one of my mods.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you saw some bolts coming from Dwarven Sphere. They come out heated just like the arrows. I don't recall if you can pick them up or not.

The bolts were added with the Dawnguard expansion. I don't know if OP has Dawnguard or not.

[image: Elder Scrolls Wikia's picture]

http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dwarven_Bolt